# Как получить offsetParent для текста внутри display: contents?

Tags: javascript

Для `div` и текста в нём `offsetParent` достаётся нормально, но для `section` и текста непосредственно в нём получается null. **Как ещё можно получить `offsetParent` желательно не проверяя всех родителей самому в цикле?**

Кстати, статья на [mdn](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent) ничего не говорит о взаимодействии `display: contents` и `offsetParent` - там только о `display: none`.

```js
function logOffsetParent(node) {
  console.log(
    node.outerHTML || node.textContent,
    '    ',
    'offsetParent' in node
      ? node.offsetParent
      : node.parentElement?.offsetParent,
  )
}

logOffsetParent(document.querySelector('div'))
logOffsetParent(document.querySelector('div').firstChild)
logOffsetParent(document.querySelector('section'))
logOffsetParent(document.querySelector('section').firstChild)
```

```css
main {
  position: relative;
}

section {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<main><section>in section<div>in div</div></section></main>
```

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77828335/4928642)